# Media players cannot access DLNA server

Tags: vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, dlna

I have Serviio setup as a DLNA server. No firewall is in place, and it works fine to my Smart TV.

Trying to access it from Windows Media Player, yet it doesn't appear at all, even using an Xbox profile.

Other players such as Foobar and VLC were recommended on forums, but they also cannot see it.

What could be the cause?

Comment: You mentioned accessing it from Windows Media Player, so from a Windows PC. Can you ping the DLNA server from your PC? Can you see the DLNA server from Windows Explorer? (Yes DLNA capable server is visible on the Windows network.. or at least that is to my experience). How are you trying to access the content? Usually you can simply access the media via windows explorer, and then the Windows Media Player will simply play the media hosted on the server.

Comment: The DLNA server is another laptop, which I can ping and access fine. DLNA server software is serviio. I don't see in in explorer or in WMP. Servioo on another machine shows up on WMP, but not from my laptop. It's very odd.